# Subgroups of $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I have to show the 12 elements and arrange them into their cyclic subgroups. (I know there are $7!/2$, but I just have to show the cyclic subgroups.) That is my question.

So I have: $e, $

$⟨(12)(34)⟩=⟨(21)(43)⟩=⟨(12)(43)⟩=⟨(21)(34)⟩, $

$⟨(13)(24)⟩=⟨(31)(42)⟩=⟨(13)(42)⟩=⟨(31)(24)⟩,$

$⟨(14)(23)⟩=⟨(14)(32)⟩=⟨(41)(23)⟩=⟨(41)(32)⟩,$

$⟨(123)⟩=⟨(132)⟩=⟨(231)⟩=⟨(213)⟩=⟨(312)⟩=⟨(321)⟩,$

$⟨(124)⟩=⟨(142)⟩=⟨(412)⟩=⟨(421)⟩=⟨(214)⟩=⟨(241)⟩,$

$⟨(134)⟩=⟨(143)⟩=⟨(413)⟩=⟨(431)⟩=⟨(341)⟩=⟨(314)⟩,$

$⟨(234)⟩=⟨(243)⟩=⟨(423)⟩=⟨(432)⟩=⟨(324)⟩=⟨(342)⟩,$

but I cant seem to get the other 4 three cycle subgroups. Does any of what I am doing make any sense at all to anybody.

Comment: Each cyclic subgroup of order $3$ contains two distinct elements of order $3$.

Comment: could you use an example, I have been looking at this for a while and that is how I learn best.

Comment: Well four subgroups of order $3$ take all $8$ elements of order $3$: you should be looking for four subgroups of order $3$, not $8$.

Comment: okay because my teacher was looking for 8. I dont know how he got 8, but is what I have right then? or at least right the way the question is phrased?

Comment: $( 1 2 3 )$ and $( 3 1 2)$ are the same element. You have indeed found all the cyclic subgroups, but your notation is kind of confusing.